# Simple program in C for appending a string to all files in a directory

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line

I need a little script that appends "\n exit" to the end of all files in ~/ae23054/ my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

     int main (void)
     {
       DIR *dp;
       struct dirent *ep;
       const char *path_dir ="~ae23054/Giuseppe";//Inserire la directory qui

       dp = opendir (path_dir);
       if (dp != NULL)
         {
           while (ep = readdir (dp)){
             printf(ep->d_name);
             char nome_file[256]=ep->d_name;

             FILE *fd=fopen(nome_file, a+);
             fprint(fd,"\nEXIT");
             fclose(fd);
           }
           (void) closedir (dp);
         }
       else
         perror ("Non posso aprire la directory");

       return -1;
}
```

But i have this error when i compile it: gcc test.c

```
esempio_giuseppe.c: In function ‘main’:
esempio_giuseppe.c:16: error: invalid initializer
esempio_giuseppe.c:18: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
esempio_giuseppe.c:18: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
esempio_giuseppe.c:18: error: for each function it appears in.)
esempio_giuseppe.c:18: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

Thanks for help

---

i have this error with :

```
char nome_file[256];

strcpy(nome_file, ep->d_name);


ae23054@el088soh:/home/risorse/ae23054/Giuseppe> gcc esempio_giuseppe.c
esempio_giuseppe.c: In function ‘main’:
esempio_giuseppe.c:18: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function   ‘strcpy’
esempio_giuseppe.c:20: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
esempio_giuseppe.c:20: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
esempio_giuseppe.c:20: error: for each function it appears in.)
esempio_giuseppe.c:20: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

Comment: Writing a shell script would have been quicker.

Comment: Please note that tilde expansion is a shell feature, `opendir()` will probably fail until you substitute the actual absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the second argument to `fopen` a string as it requires a `const char*`

```
FILE *fd=fopen(nome_file, "a+");
                          ^  ^
                          ^  ^
```

instead of

```
FILE *fd=fopen(nome_file, a+);
```

See also @AlterMann answer regarding your file name buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `char nome_file[256]=ep->d_name;`
You need to use `strcpy()` to copy strings like, `strcpy(nome_file,ep->d_name);` and also change `FILE *fd=fopen(nome_file, a+);` to `FILE *fd=fopen(nome_file, "a+");`